# How does one share Samsung camera "Virtual Shot" (3D spin-around) photos?

Tags: samsung, camera, file-sharing

I recently traveled to Europe and took dozens of beautiful 3D spin-around shots using Samsung built-in camera's **"Virtual Shot"** mode photos.

These look amazing on my phone, but I want to share them with the world. In the past I've been able to share photos to a javascript-powered website, such as 360 photos via Microsoft's Photosynth.

How can I share these spin-around 3D photos?

*Note: if there is no way to do it currently, I am an app developer and web programmer so I'd be happy to build one myself, so let me know if there's any information on the data they are stored in as well*

Answer (score 1):

Othr than an MP4 export, you can't. You have to take your photos in Phogy (app, gif, or mp4) or Fyuse (web or gif). Both are lower in pixel quality (slightly) but allow for sharing the interactive experience. The pro version of phogy has higher quality but still lower than 4k.

I hope someone makes a parallax  player that takes raw videos, then all video cameras could share it.

Answer (score -1):

If you click the share button while viewing the shot, you're given the option of sharing as a video file, which converts it to an mp4.

Comment: This is good. I would like to have it interactive, since that is, well, the whole novelty of the thing. Perhaps there is a interactive MP4 player that supports similar interactivity, such as tilting, or scrubbing on the screen?

Comment: I've transferred all my photos to my computer. Did this delete all the 3d spin around information? I can't find it anymore

Comment: @Jonathan Resend the files back to your Samsung phone, that you transferred to your computer. The phone would process the image(s) in a while (usually a few mins but can be up-to a few hours) and would start detecting the images as virtual shots. Next share the virtual shot and you'd be given the option to share the image as a video file. This is where you get an mp4 video of the virtual moment. Share this video file with whom ever you want.