# Samsung's stock camera app, where are Virtual Shot 3D photos stored?

Tags: samsung, camera, photos

I've got a Samsung S7 and the default camera has a [Virtual Shot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxgwEeh4V_E) mode where you walk around an object to take an array of photos as one photo. You can then view it in the default gallery app and turn the device or swipe left/right to see the 3D effect.

My question is, **where are these Virtual Shot 3D photo files stored?**

When I take such a photo it stores a single .jpg, when I connect a USB to my laptop I can see it in this folder (btw the phone is not jailbroken or anything)

```
\Samsung\Card\DCIM\Camera\20210703_124317.jpg
```

But that is just the first of the array of photos which acts like a thumbnail sort of. The reason that I want to get all the photos is to edit them as a 3D photo or print them side-by-side for a stereo photo 3D viewer. I've looked in the folders listed below, but I can't find where they are stored.

```
\Samsung\Phone\DCIM\Camera\  
\Samsung\Phone\Android\data\com.samsung.android.coreapps\  
\Samsung\Card\DCIM\Camera\  
\Samsung\Card\Android\data\com.samsung.android.coreapps\
```

EDIT: the single JPG that I found is actually just one photo, the file size is too small for multiple photos but I've also opened it in a binary editor to verify it isn't some container file or concatenated files.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but for e.g. Panorama photos, some Samsung devices will just stitch the images together. Have you examined the single `.jpg` to see if that is the case?

Comment: Edited my question just now, yes I've examined the .JPG file and it is indeed just one photo image, not the virtual collection of photos.

Comment: The linked YouTube video looks more like the outcome of a virtual shot is a video which is just played not the common way. Therefore I would search for a motion jpeg video.

Comment: Possibly related: [How does one share Samsung camera “Virtual Shot” (3D spin-around) photos?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126149/44325)